# Look for two names in sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula that sums a range in a table and works fine if there is one name like 'Joe Bloggs'

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[Credit],Table2[Residents],[@[Resident Name]],Table2[Subcategory],"Prior Current Fin")
```

What i need is for it to find 'Joe Bloggs' and 'ZZ Joe Bloggs, bearing in mind that the formula should read

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[Credit],Table2[Residents],"ZZ & [@[Resident Name]],Table2[Subcategory],"Prior Current Fin")
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: how can `Table2[Residents]` be both `'Joe Bloggs' and 'ZZ Joe Bloggs'` at the same time?  Do you mean where `Table2[Residents]` is `'Joe Bloggs' OR 'ZZ Joe Bloggs'`?

Comment: If it just needs to end in Joe Bloggs, you could use: `"*"&[@[Resident Name]]`

Comment: Sorry, yes, meant or

Comment: @Rory Thanks, worked great#

Comment: @Rory Actullay that dosent work as there may be Jane&Joe Bloggs in the table. Needs to be ZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array and wrap the `SUMIFS` in an additional `SUM` function, like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table2[Credit],Table2[Residents],{"ZZ ",""}&[@[Resident Name]],Table2[Subcategory],"Prior Current Fin"))
```